# Javascript/Jquery: Compute the values based on the values or null values of input type

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am new to Javascript/Jquery. Below is my code that can compute an average (A) value as long as there are 3 present values in the input.

[image]

Here is the jquery code

```
$(".q-value, .e-value, .t-value").click(function(){
        let currentRow = $(this).closest('tr');
        let EValue = parseFloat(currentRow.find('.e-value').val());
        let QValue = parseFloat(currentRow.find('.q-value').val());
        let TValue = parseFloat(currentRow.find('.t-value').val());
        currentRow.find('.a-value-core').val((EValue  + QValue + TValue ) / 3);
        currentRow.find('.a-value-support').val((EValue  + QValue + TValue ) / 3);
        currentRow.find('.a-value-research').val((EValue  + QValue + TValue ) / 3);});
```

I would like to set an average value even if the Q or E or T input is null However, A value is not computing. when Q or E or T value is null.

For example.

1. Q = 5, E = null and T = null then A value should be 5
2. Q = 5, E = 2 and T = null then A value should be 3.5
3. Q = 5, E = 5 and T = 5 then A value should be 5

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
Number(currentRow.find('.*-value').val());
```

instead of

```
parseFloat(currentRow.find('.*-value').val());
```

as when no value is selected in the dropdown, .val() returns an empty string, not null, and parseFloat("") returns NaN. When you try to add NaN to any number answer returned is still a NaN and your result field stays empty.

**Few more notes:**

1. What type of elements are .a-value-**** ? They need to be textfields or such to use .val(). If not, use .text()
2. Your formula to calculate average of only available numbers will not work when you divide by 3, irrespective of the input. You need to change the logic there as well.
3. I would use .change instead of .click for a dropdown

PS: It's always a good idea to use console.log(variable) for quick debugging and look for error messages in the console inside the Devtools of the browser and share the same with your question

Comment: Answer is good, just add a check that, if user enters a non numeric value then "NUMBER" function returns NAN, and that will again given an incorrect answer. You can do it like: (!isNaN(currentRow.find('.t-value').val()) ? Number(currentRow.find('.t-value').val()): 0)

Comment: Yes that takes care textfield input as well.... I presumed that the dropdown has only number options or empty when nothing is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Hello @AlwaysaLearner noted on your notes. as for the computations, I have to change the logic for the computation by creating a counter for Q, E or T value !== 0 then counter + 1 inside an if else statement. below is the code

```
//COMPUTE THE AVERAGE PER ROW
    $(".q-value, .e-value, .t-value").change(function(){
        let currentRow = $(this).closest('tr');
        let EValue = Number(currentRow.find('.e-value').val());
        let QValue = Number(currentRow.find('.q-value').val());
        let TValue = Number(currentRow.find('.t-value').val());
        let counter = 0

        if (QValue !== 0){
            counter = counter + 1
        }
        if (EValue !== 0){
            counter = counter + 1
        }
        if (TValue !== 0){
            counter = counter + 1
        }

        currentRow.find('.clerical-value-core').val((EValue  + QValue + TValue ) / Number(counter));
        currentRow.find('.technical-value-core').val((EValue  + QValue + TValue ) / Number(counter));
        currentRow.find('.a-value-support').val((EValue  + QValue + TValue ) / Number(counter)); });
```

and now It works perfectly. I also change the handler .change and also applied Number function for each field.

Comment: You may not have to use `Number` for the `counter` as it is created inside your codes and treated as a number. Also, if there is an option to select 0 for q, e or t values then you may want to change the code to something like  `if(currentRow.find('.e-value').val() != "") counter ++` for every one of them and finally calculate the average only `if (counter > 0)`